# Redis sentinel As a windows service

Tags: windows, redis, redis-sentinel

I downloaded the sentinel.conf file from https://download.redis.io/redis-stable/sentinel.conf and put it in to my default Redis installed location **C:\Program Files\Redis**. Then following changes are applied to the configuration file.

File changes

- port 26379
- daemonize yes
- sentinel monitor mymaster {IP address} {Port} 1
- sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 30000
- sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1
- sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 3000

Then i was able to register redis sentinel as a windows service using following command

**SC CREATE sentinel binpath= ""C:\Program Files\Redis\redis-server.exe" --service-run sentinel.conf --sentinel**

But following error is occurred when i tried to start the service from service window .

**"Windows could not start the sentinel service on Local Computer.
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. "**

Do i have to change the configuration file or the Redis windows version(currently i am using Redis 3.2)?

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old and unsupported Windows port of Redis by Microsoft (called *OpenTech Redis*).
I suggest you take a look at Memurai: a project actively maintained and supported (which, by the way, derives from that Microsoft project ([see here](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/commit/287e01c68ce9ec6e7a739c19b04b1dfc253326e3)).

It both has a free developer version and Enterprise licenses.

Disclaimer: I work in Memurai.